# How do you change the value of a parameter in the same php equation

Tags: php, parameters

I am trying to change the value of the 'text' parameter for each 'column_id' parameter. For example:

```
'column_id' => 'email'
'text' => 'foresthill@mailto.com
```

and

```
'column_id => 'phone'
'text' => '555-555-5555'
```

The equation works if I have one column_id and text parameter, but when I try to change the value of the second column_id 'phone' to text value 555-555-5555, the phone number shows up in the 'email' column.

How can I make the text value to go into its own column_id, like this:

```
email = example@example.com
phone = 555-555-5555.
```

Code:

```
//********************** Update Pulse Columns for a specific pulse ***********************      
$put_fields = array(
     //monday.com board and user id values
     'board_id' => '194618490',
     'column_id' => 'email1',
     'pulse_id' => 197299328,
     'text' => 'foresthill@mailto.com'
);    
$put_fields = array(
     //monday.com board and user id values
     'board_id' => '194618490',
     'column_id' => 'phone',
     'pulse_id' => 197299328,
     'text' => '555-555-5555'
);
$ch =  curl_init('https://api.monday.com:443/194618490/columns/email1/text.json?api_key=api_key');
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'ARPR');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, URL. $api);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $put_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
//$curl_result = curl_exec($ch);
//curl_close($ch);
print "<pre>";
print_r($curl_result);
print "</pre>";
```

Comment: Where in your code are you attempting to make the change? (It is also distracting that your samples at the top are missing single quotes. Please be careful to provide accurate examples.)

Comment: I am trying to make the change in $put_fields = array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [monday.com doc](https://developers.monday.com/#!/boards/PUT_version_boards_board_id_columns_column_id_text_format), that api will update exactly one column. The URL includes the column name. It sounds like you need two separate calls.

---

The second `$put_fields=` *overwrites* the contents of the first `$put_fields=`. So by the time it gets to the curl stuff, *there is no* `'column_id' => 'email`.

One approach might be: make the `column_id` itself an array, such as

`column_id => ['email' : theemail, 'phone': 5555555]`

Obviously, that would require changes to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $put_fields);`.

Another option, list the keys separately in the `$put_fields` array. It is not clear why you need `column_id` since it is not used.

Comment: the column_id is needed to place the value of 'text' in that column called email or phone into the CRM where the data is being sent to.

Comment: What changes would you make to the curl_setupt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $put_fields);?

Comment: A quick read of the [monday.com doc](https://developers.monday.com/#!/boards/PUT_version_boards_board_id_columns_column_id_text_format) indicates that api updates exactly one column. It looks like your call is to update `email1` column. I am perfectly willing to be wrong, but I think you will need two post calls to different URLs, one for each column name (email, phone).

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus this is only logical, because there only is one `column_id`.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus making 2 post calls did it.  You have the correct answer how do I give you credit.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. You can click on the check mark beside the answer to accept it. Thanks!